# jQuery appendTo on page load

Tags: jquery

Ok relevant HTML:

```
<div rel="" id="CartridgeDisplays" class="category section ">
    <h3 class="categoryTitle parent">Cartridge Displays</h3>                
</div>

<div rel="" id="ColdCastBronzeresinFigurines" class="category section ">
    <h3 class="categoryTitle">Cold Cast Bronze resin Figurines</h3>             
</div>

<div rel="CartridgeDisplays" id="Collectableitems" class="category section child">
    <h3 class="categoryTitle">Collectable items</h3>                
</div>

<div rel="CartridgeDisplays" id="CommercialDisplaysandClocks" class="category section child">
    <h3 class="categoryTitle">Commercial Displays and Clocks</h3>               
</div>
```

And this jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.child').appendTo($('# + $(this).attr('rel') + '));
    }); 
</script>
```

So what i want to happen is on page load, is all the DIV's with a class of 'child' to be appended to the DIV that has the same id as the class:child DIV's rel attribute. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: The names you use for IDs might need some .. emm .. work. Actually the whole thing looks semantically broken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your string concatenation is wrong.  It should be: `'#' + $(this).attr('rel')`.  And you'll need to put it in a call to `.each()`.

```
$('.child').each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#' + $(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

Explanation: in your code, `$(this)` refers to the `document`.  In order to refer to the `.child` div, you need to iterate through them.