# jQuery appendTo() raising exception

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a Web app that loads an external HTML page using require.js and text.js, and then uses jQuery to extract elements from it and plop them into the main page.

I am doing something like this:

`$('.menu-popup', frag).addClass('invisible').appendTo($(document))`

The `frag` variable is a DOM document-fragment that contains the HTML loaded using text.js. The menu-class CSS class identifies the elements I need to extract. I am adding the invisible CSS class (which sets `display: none`) so that the addition of the elements doesn’t mess up the user experience. However, when I open the page in the browser, I get this:

`TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'e.createDocumentFragment')`

The problem is in the `appendTo()` call at the very end. If I remove it and instead assign the results of the expression to a variable, nothing (visibly) goes wrong. I’ve tried every possible permutation of the code I can think of. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try to append to body instead of document

Comment: You mention that nothing seems to go wrong if you cache the `.addClass()` call. Does that mean you do `var foo = $('.menu-popup', frag).addClass('invisible'); foo.appendTo($(document));`? Or do you not do the `foo.appendTo($(document));` statement? Or something else? Do these give the same error?

Comment: There are issues with fragments in jQuery, using them as context or appending to the document are some of the issues I've encountered before, so I'd say the workaround would be `$('body').append( $('<div />').append(frag).find('.menu-popup') )`, but it seems you've found the answer in a totally unrelated question ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It now works. I followed the advice in [the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718613/jquery-appendto-on-page-load?rq=1); it started working a few page-reloads thereafter.